# Python: cannot import scrypt from hashlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, hashlib, scrypt

I need to use scrypt algorithm and since I´m already using hashlib, I figured... why not? I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957457/can-not-import-scrypt-from-hashlib) and it pointed out OpenSSL 1.1+ was necessary. Also, according to [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html):

> hashlib.scrypt(password, *, salt, n, r, p, maxmem=0, dklen=64)
>
> ...
>
> Availability: OpenSSL 1.1+.
>
> New in version 3.6.

I made sure to have the latest version of openssl:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

I also tried to run python3.6 and python3 (3.4) and both say they cannot import scrypt:

```
# python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 10 2018, 17:08:37)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
>>> from hashlib import scrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'scrypt'
```

As you can see, other methods like `pbkdf2_hmac` work. What could be wrong?

Also, what is the `*` in `hashlib.scrypt(password, *, salt, n, r, p, maxmem=0, dklen=64)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mac is running with `OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018`.
I reproduced your import symptoms with python3.6,
and found that `scrypt` imported just fine with python3.7.
You might consider trying 3.7.

The `*` in the signature is a relatively new syntax
which marks the end of positional arguments.
So you can't invoke as `scrypt('secret', 'mySalt')`.
You need to specify keyword args, e.g. `scrypt('secret', salt='mySalt')`.
The intent is to make it harder to call incorrectly by using a mistaken arg order.
This tends to be especially important for crypto APIs,
where many of the args are opaque and hard to validate.

Comment: you are right. I took me a lot to compile from source python 3.7 but it worked. I wish the docs were a little more clear about that. And thank you for explaining the positional args syntax. I was not aware of it.